# Separate RTL css file using postcss-loader and RTLCSS in webpack

Tags: webpack, postcss, webpack-5, postcss-loader, rtlcss

How can I create a separate RTL css file using postcss-loader and rtlcss? I added to `postcss.config.js` but I can't find any information about defining the output file. I would like to use `{name}.rtl.{ext}` format, just don't know how to define it within the webpack or postcss config files.

webpack.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                        }, {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                url: false,
                                importLoaders: 1
                            }
                        }, {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }, {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    };
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = ({ file, options, env }) => ({
    plugins: {
        autoprefixer: {
            cascade: false
        },
        rtlcss: {}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two `Webpack` configurations, one with all the rules that you need and a second one only for the CSS files, including the `postcss-loader` using the `rtlcss` plugin. Later on, in the `webpack.config.js`, you should return an array with these configurations.

Here you have an example. With this configuration two CSS will be generated, `[name].ltr.css` and `[name].rtl.css`. The last one is the CSS file with all the rules flipped using `rtlcss`:

> Note: `getCommon` is a utility function to return the common configuration to avoid repeating the same code twice.

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const rtlcss = require('rtlcss');

const getCommon = (dir) => ({
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './index.js',
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: `styles/[name].${dir}.css`
        }),
    ]
});

module.exports = [
    {
        ...getCommon('ltr'),
        module: {
            rules: [
                /**
                 ** Here you can place the rules
                 ** for all the files that you want to process
                 ** apart from CSSs
                 **/
                {
                    test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        },
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }     
    },
    {
        ...getCommon('rtl'),
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        },
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                postcssOptions: {
                                    plugins: [
                                        rtlcss()
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        
    }
];
```